# How to define common import packages with resolution optional in build.bnd

Tags: java, osgi, bnd, bndtools

I wanted to import some packages in all bundles with resolution optional using build.bnd

I have tried below code but it's showing only package name in imports, not resolution optional

```
common-imports:${if;${debug};com.example.foo.debug\;resolution:=optional}
Import-Package: \
${common-imports}, \
*
```

It should show
    *Import:com.example.foo.debug;resolution:=optional* but its showing 
    *Import:com.example.foo.debug*

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 backslashes before the `;resolution`.

`common-imports: ${if;${debug};com.example.foo.debug\\;resolution:=optional}`

This is because the bnd file is a Java properties file and the properties file processing will remove one of the backslashes.